# Where are promo train tickets valid in the Netherlands

Tags: trains, tickets, netherlands, group-travel

I'm currently part of a group of scouts in Delft and we (12 aged 15 through 17 & 2 over 18s) and we are trying to get to Amsterdam as cheaply as possible. We have looked at group tickets (https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/losse-kaartjes/p/ns-groepsretour) but these appear to need printing so aren't practical (we are camping and don't have a printer) we have some mobile phones (not enough for 1 each - would it be possible to show the tickets on these?).

However, I then found a link to what is described as a promo day ticket at 12.50EUR (https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/s/dagkaart-juli-1606072) but I'm struggling to find any information, where are these tickets valid for and is there any time restrictions? And would we need to print off something to use them?

Apologies for the formatting as we are sending this from a mobile over dodgy WiFi. Huge thanks to anyone who can fix it.

Edit: quick additional question, what is the ideal payment and it used with a UK credit card?

Comment: iDEAL is specific to Dutch banks (typically requires a Dutch debit card - not a credit card - and  a security token device).

Comment: Is there a kruidvat nearby? It appears they are currently selling tickets. Also: you can print for very low prices at a library or at a hema shop.

Comment: @J.Constantine You should post that as an answer, NS regularly sells special day tickets through retailers like Albert Heijn, HEMA, Kruidvat, etc. If such an offer is running currently, that's an excellent option. There are at least a couple of Kruidvat locations in Delft (with a large one close to the Zuipoort shopping area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this special day ticket can be used at any time during one calendar day, like a regular day ticket. NS regularly offers special deals for day tickets like that.

The problem is that you also need to print it out (that's the e-ticket option) or to have an anonymous OV-chipkaart on which you could load the ticket (the card itself costs EUR 7.50).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if we could get away with 1 card or if we would need 1 each?

Comment: @skifans That's one each, unfortunately. Maybe going with one of the online options and finding a print shop somewhere could be worth it? There is one in Delft across the Westvest next to the station.